Ubuntu Studio 24.04 boot problems after fresh install
I had no problems installing Ubuntu Studio 23.10, but now, after update to 24.04 never booted. So I started with a fresh install. All seems to work, but after first reboot same problem. Won't start. I tried to install in a new ssd disk, in case the old one had any defective sector, but still same problem. How can I see what is happening after grub load?
Regards

You'll need to put a few more details (i.e. error messages, log files) to hopefully get useful responses. Have you tried pressing F2 on the graphical boot screen to see if there is any useful console output?
